# Postgresql TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMPTZ: is there any difference in data stored?

Tags: postgresql

If I inherit a `Postgresql` database filled with `TIMESTAMP` type, and feel the need to convert them all to `TIMESTAMPTZ` type, is this a simple process requiring only:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN the_time_stamp TYPE TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

I have such a database, and all the timestamps within it, created in a timezone different to mine (and the server's) behave such that they seem to be stored internally as TIMESTAMPTZ anyway. That is, I have two clients (one write, one read, neither of which is in UTC zone), and when I read, the timestamps written in zone1 are correct when read in zone2, implying (to me) they have been converted and stored in UTC format between the write and read. It makes me wonder if:

- Are all timestamps stored in identical format in the database, and the only differences occur in the way input/output is handled, according to the timezone(s) of the connected client(s)?

This seems like such a clear and simple thing to state if it were true, but I cannot find it stated clearly and/or simply...

Comment: "*I have two clients, neither of which is in UTC zone*" - are you saying these set a session timezone on their connections?

Comment: To be honest: I'm unsure - the client writing is via a Poco library wrapper; the client reading is psql. As noted, I inherited this database, and the data in it seems fine... but it is all in `timestamp` format which has become a limiting factor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, both `timestamp` and `timestamp with time zone` are stored in the same fashion: an 8-byte integer that is the offset from 2000-01-01 00:00:00 in microseconds.

The difference is the semantics: while `timestamp with time zone` is stored as offset from midnight 2000-01-01 in UTC, no time zone conversion is made for `timestamp`.

That means that the table has to be rewritten if you change the data type, because the point of reference changes. If the `timezone` parameter is set to `UTC`, the values won't change, but there is no optimization in PostgreSQL that avoids the table rewrite in this case.

Comment: Does that mean that the `TIMESTAMP` values are stored relative to the time zone of the server, whereas `TIMESTAMPTZ` are stored relative to UTC? Is that the essential data difference? Each is relative to a different time reference? Because without such a conversion to some reference time zone, I do not understand how the two different clients can support the correct result.

Comment: You got it. To be precise: a `timestamp` is stored as offset to midnight 2000-01-01 in the `timezone` that was active when you inserted the value.