# Timezone aware uniqueness constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a timesheet app, used by users from multiple timezones. I am trying to introduce a unique constraint, that only allows users to `clock_in` or `clock_out` once per day in the local timezone.

Please refer to the following table declaration:

```sql
Table "public.entries"
---------------------------------------------
  Column   |              Type              |
---------------------------------------------
id         | bigint                         |
user_id    | bigint                         |
entry_type | string                         | enum(clock_in, clock_out)
created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |
```

But little lost on how to handle the timezone-aware uniqueness.

Update:

- I am considering 0:00 hrs to 23:55 hrs of local time zone as day.
- User's timezone is stored in the `users` table but can move to the `entries` table if it helps with constraints.

Comment: Your only option is to use `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `timestamp with time zone` aka `timestamptz` doesn't actually store a timezone. It's confusingly named. The only difference afaik is in the default formatting for it. And actually you basically only ever want to use `timestamptz`.

Comment: @sudo it actually does store a time zone that is `UTC`. It  is implied but it is the time zone `timestamptz` values are stored as. That is why it is the preferred option, you always know what time zone the stored value is in, so you have a base from which to convert to any other time zone.

Comment: What happens if a shift crosses midnight? In other words define a day? Also what if people have to punch in/out for lunch? Then you would have two clock in's and out's per 'day'. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I haven't thought about midnight shifts but regarding lunch punch in/out we can always add entry_type.

Comment: Where “local timezone” comes from? Is it stored in your database somewhere?

Comment: @Envek It is stored in the user table, but can move to the entries table if it helps with constraint.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Eh, I still wouldn't characterize it that way. timestamptz is 64 bits on disk, all of which are representing the microseconds since epoch. No concept of time zone is encoded in that. Postgres converts that to/from a human-readable UTC timestamp string during select or insert, is all.

Comment: @sudo. The `epoch` for `timestamptz` starting at `2000-01-01 UTC` per answer here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848819/postgresql-timestamp-and-timestamptz-is-there-any-difference-in-data-stored/69848908#69848908) and in the source at: `~/src/include/datatype/timestamp.h`. This is what makes it work, the timestamp is anchored at a `UTC` time.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Right, but the column isn't storing a timezone. Postgres just understands it to be anchored to a particular UTC time.

Comment: @sudo, For `timestamptz`, Postgres knows the stored value is at `UTC` so there is a timezone associated with the value. You can argue all you want but it does not change that fact and that this fact is why you should store in `timestamptz` as you know what time zone you are starting with.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question and wrote a bad answer, so here's a new one...

I assume this is a typical client-server-db setup. You need to obtain the local time zone from the client that's clocking in/out the user; Postgres doesn't know what it is. We'll figure out the user's local date from that and store it. Then we'll have a uniqueness index on <user, local date>.

I thought there'd be fancier ways to do this by storing the `timestamptz` with a separate time zone col and calculating the date within the uniqueness index, but Postgres doesn't allow us to use `date_trunc` within an index. So we're going to denormalize just a little and make things a lot easier with this additional `date` col.

```
CREATE TABLE clock_in (
  user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,  -- stores microseconds since epoch
  local_date date NOT NULL,  -- stores the <year, month, day> in whatever timezone the user clocked in from
  -- optional for bookkeeping purposes: time_zone text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(user_id, local_date)
);
```

Take a look at the [official date/time type docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) for further explanation of the above. IMO you shouldn't rely on DB constraints to reject bad user input. They're more of a second line of defense meant to ensure a self-consistent database. First your server should query the last clock-in and error out if it was in the same day, and also error if there was no clock-in that day. You'll be able to yield more useful error messages that way. Then you can insert...

```
INSERT INTO clock_in(user_id, created_at, local_date) (
  SELECT 1, now(),
  (date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'insert_users_timezone_here'))::date
);
```

Usage example for a client who has indicated it's in the `PST` timezone:

```
me=# CREATE TABLE clock_in ( user_id bigint NOT NULL, created_at timestamptz NOT NULL, local_date date NOT NULL, UNIQUE(user_id, local_date) );
CREATE TABLE
me=# INSERT INTO clock_in(user_id, created_at, local_date) ( SELECT 1, now(), (date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'PST'))::date );
INSERT 0 1
me=# INSERT INTO clock_in(user_id, created_at, local_date) ( SELECT 1, now(), (date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'PST'))::date );
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "clock_in_user_id_local_date_key"
DETAIL: Key (user_id, local_date)=(1, 2022-04-13) already exists.
me=# INSERT INTO clock_in(user_id, created_at, local_date) ( SELECT 1, now(), (date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'PST' + interval '10' hour))::date );
INSERT 0 1
me=#
```

Then you'd do the same for clock-outs.

Using `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp` is deliberate. You should almost never use `timestamp`, for reasons other answers describe well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll probably want to use a native datetime datatype and a range one at that, e.g. `tstzrange` (with timezone) / `tsrange` (without timezone) – they allow you to natively store a start and end time – see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN

You can optionally add an exclusion constraint to ensure no two shifts overlap – see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT if that's all you really want to ensure, then that might be enough.

If you definitely want to ensure there's only one shift starting or ending per day, you can use a function to derive a unique index:

```sql
create unique index INDEX_NAME on TABLE_NAME (date_trunc('day', lower(column_name)))
```

For your example specifically:

```
create unique index idx_unique_shift_start_time on entries (user_id, date_trunc('day', lower(active_during)))

create unique index idx_unique_shift_end_time on entries (user_id, date_trunc('day', upper(active_during)))
```

These two indexes take the lower or upper bounds of the range (i.e. the start time or end time), then truncate to just the day (i.e. drop the hours, minutes, seconds etc) and then combine with the `user_id` to give us a unique key.

Comment: I tried this too, but `date_trunc` isn't usable in an index. `ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`. You'd also need to put the timezone into its third parameter.

Comment: According to https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/dcc563d10912241656t61c23a63s1c4c7de71e67facf%40mail.gmail.com `date_trunc` should be immutable for timestamps without timezone, so if changing the column type is an option, that might help. I'm not sure if the function signature changes to immutable automatically, so it could require wrapping in another function that is immutable.